# Heroku ignoring config vars and database in app.json for a Node.js app

Tags: node.js, heroku, config

I am trying to set a config/environment var in config file *app.json* for a Node.js app deployed to Heroku, but the var is undefined when I try to access it in my Node.js code. I have managed to find a very simple example which is not working:

- download the Node.js "official" very simple example:

  ```
  $ git clone https://github.com/heroku/node-js-getting-started.git
  $ cd node-js-getting-started
  ```
- edit *app.json* and add this to the end:

  ```
    ...
    "image": "heroku/nodejs",
    "env" : {
      "MYVAR": "12345" 
    }
  }
  ```
- replace the last line of *index.js* with:

  ```
    .listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${ PORT }, var is ${ process.env.MYVAR }`))
  ```
- deploy to Heroku:

  ```
     $ heroku create
     $ git add . & git commit -s "changes" & git push heroku master
     $ heroku open
  ```

Now, I get "Listening on 24619, var is undefined" in the logs. I suspect *app.json* is being ignored since if I add

```
       "addons": ["heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev"]
```

then, no database is linked to the app. Everything works as expected, however, if I run in my terminal:

```
        $ heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev
        $ heroku config:set MYVAR=12345
```

Why is the config var undefined and the database not initialised for the app in spite of the information in the manifest?

Comment: What if you log out `process.env.MYVAR`? I wouldn't expect the `NODE_` prefix. It's unclear how this connects to the database issue, either.

Comment: My fault, @jonrsharpe. I wrote NODE_MYVAR instead of MYVAR in my question. I have corrected it. It is with process.env.MY_VAR that I get the undefined.